# Need help with navigation list

Tags: lightning-design-system

I am trying to do something simular to this https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/navigation/.
But all my `<li>` are active since i am loading in the content, how can i do this so only the contect clikced on is active ?.
This is what i have so far.

```
<ul class="slds-navigation-list--vertical slds-has-block-links--space">
    <li class="slds-is-active">
        <a class="slds-navigation-list--vertical__action slds-text-link--reset" aria-describedby="entity-header" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.handleSidebarFolderListEvent}">
           <ui:outputText value="{!v.folder.Name}"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And it looks like this

[image]

Comment: So you want only one active? Or all like you have? Or only active on hover? Or active after click?

Comment: active after click, and remove active from those that are not being clicked.